# After Magento2.2.0 upgrade: ReferenceError: initializeFieldsetDataByDefault is not defined

Tags: magento2, category, upgrade

I've upgraded my magento version from Magento2.1.4 to Magento2.2.0 via composer. Everything seems to work fine so far. But when I browse the category at backend, it doesn't show the tabs after Content http://prntscr.com/h4su2f and it shows error in firebug i.e. ReferenceError: initializeFieldsetDataByDefault is not defined

I've installed fresh magento2.2.0 on local and it's working fine there.

Can anybody help me to get this fixed?

Thanks in advance!